# _NET_WM_NAME does not match shown title of window

Tags: x11, xlib

The text in the atom `_NET_WM_NAME` often doesn't match what XFCE's panel shows.

For example, gedit might show up as `app.d (~/GIT/Clemote/server/source) - gedit` while `_NET_WM_NAME` returns `gedit`. Other windows, such as Chromium, does not return anything.

How do I get the title which matches the one shown in XFCE panel?

What I'm doing in pseudo-code:

```
grab all windows by using XQueryTree with the root window
get the _NET_WM_NAME atom
for each window
  if visible, print the value of the atom
```

Example output:

```
Xfce Terminal
gedit
```

Comment: Have you tried _NET_WM_ICON_NAME or WM_ICON_NAME?

Comment: @n.m. `_NET_WM_ICON_NAME` just gives me "xfwm" on one of the windows. Might be issues with my code.